# Mule: How to do NTLM authentication in Mule ESB?

Tags: authentication, mule, ntlm

How to do NTLM authentication in Mule (Mule Studio 3.5)?

On Internet i have found following ways: 
`<http:connector name="HTTP_HTTPS" ... proxyHostname="..." proxyPort="80" proxyPassword="..." proxyUsername="Castor.Acer">
<spring:property name="proxyNtlmAuthentication" value="true"/>
</http:connector>`

`<http:connector name="httpConnector" proxyHostname="someHost" proxyPort="8080"
proxyNtlmAuthentication="true" proxyUsername="someUser" proxyPassword="somePass" />`

But none worked for me, or am i configuring it properly?

Presently i am using it as following:

`<mule>
    <http:connector name="HTTPO"  proxyHostname="10.91.17.170" proxyPort="81" proxyUsername="administrator" proxyPassword="Psw0rd123" 
                     doc:name="HTTP\HTTPS">
        <spring:property name="proxyNtlmAuthentication" value="true"/>
    </http:connector>
    <flow name="testPraveenFlow1" doc:name="testPraveenFlow1">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"   address="http://localhost:81/Orcha" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <custom-transformer class="com.CreateBook" doc:name="Java"/>
        <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" method="POST"  contentType="text/xml" doc:name="HTTP" address="http://10.91.17.170:81/Orch2012/Orch.svc/jobs" connector-ref="HTTPO"/>
        <byte-array-to-string-transformer doc:name="Byte Array to String"/>
        <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </flow>
</mule>`

Output:
`401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.</h2>
  You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.`

Comment: Hello, have you found solution already? I am planning to use mule with NTLM too. Thanks

Comment: No. I used Java Code in between to resolve it. If you find please do share answer with us. Thanks